# Re-naming chart legend in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, charts, graph, ms-access-2007

In an auto-generated chart based on a query (I dragged the chart object onto a blank form to start it), the chart itself is displaying and updating properly, datawise, but I want to change the Legend from reading "SumOfAvgOfield1" and "SumOfAvgOfield2" to regular words suitable for final presentations. But I can't find a way to change it!

Comment: Is renaming the columns (fields) in the query not an option for you? You can change the heading of the columns to read, say, Total: Sum(AvgField2)

Comment: This may be of interest: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA010345801033.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a late answer, but I was just having a similar issue and figured someone else might benefit from knowing how to get rid of the 'SumOf' labels.

1. In design view, right click on the chart and select 'Properties'.
2. Choose the Data tab.
3. The 'Row Source' field is the one you're going to be interested.

In there you can see various places where it's labeling your data:

```
Sum() AS [SumOfData]
```

Just edit the text right in the properties window and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

This is WAY late, but here's what I found (Yes we still use office 2007)
Open the form in PivotTable View. Open Property Sheet. Highlight the column you want to change the Legend Caption for.  Choose the Captions Tab in the properties window.  There you can change the captions for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Had 4 charts on a form.  3 would let me edit the Heading of the Chart, the  4th would not.  Read a lot of posts that did not pertain.  Noticed the datasheet for the 4th chart was completely empty.

SOLUTION:  Clicked on chart until the datasheet appeared.  Added mock field headings and mock data to datasheet.  I could then click on chart and edit the chart's Heading.  You can also highlight and change the color of selected words in the chart's Heading.  Very Nice!
Good luck,
Vancer

Comment: "Clicked on chart until the datasheet appeared" -- do you mean multiple clicks, long click or smth else? Looks like your answer is helpful, but sounds somewhat vague in some aspects.

Comment: I did this again today (3/8/2017) and it worked a treat.  In Design View, click on the Chart.  If when you click on the chart the datasheet does not appear, you can right-click the chart, choose datasheet.  Notice all the fields in the datasheet (looks like a spreadsheet) are blank.  Enter "Date" in the first field, "Test1" in the second, "Test2" in the third field (without the quotes).  Now, enter a date under Date, and numbers in the Test1 and Test2 fields.  You'll see the chart updating as you do this.  You can now click on the chart and edit the Legend.

Answer (score 0):

The SumofAverageOfFiled1, etc is automatically generated.  Even if you edit it in the datasheet, it changes back (or at least that is my experience).  What I did to get around this is add a Rectangle and fill it with white and size it to cover up the "Sumof" captions.  You can Bring to Front the Rectangle.  Then you can add text boxes to label the chart's bars to read the way you want them.  Drag them over the Rectange and Bring to Front.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere I looked it said just change the Pivot Table to change the Legend Entry.

Well, let me tell you.

First, if you have no Pivot Table that you can see do the following:

1. go to **design view** and select the *form*
2. right click and hit **Properties**. Scroll through till you see `AllowPivotTableView` and select *yes*.

Now you can go and change the column headers!

Answer (score 0):

This could help

Select xxxxx, yyyyy from zzzz

Chart0.ChartSeriesCollection(0).DisplayName = ![XXXXX]
Chart0.ChartSeriesCollection(1).DisplayName = ![YYYYY]

Was very difficult to me to find a way to do it.